# How a Python code to store integer in list and then find the sum of integer stored in the List

Tags: python-3.x

List of integer value passed through input function and then stored in a list. After which performing the operation to find the sum of all the numbers in the list

```
lst = list( input("Enter the list of items :") )  
sum_element = 0
for i in lst:
    sum_element = sum_element+int(i)
print(sum_element)
```

Comment: So, you wrote this code. Okay. But what is the question?

Comment: List of integer value passed through input function and then stored in a list. After which performing the operation to find the sum of all the numbers in the list

Comment: No, not what the task is. What is your question related to the task and your code? Does it behave unexpectedly? Does it return an error message? Do you ask for help to improve it? Please elaborate on what you expect from SO users to help you with.

Comment: yes the output is not coming correctly.

Comment: The code i have written is wrong may be.

Comment: Then, please provide a sample input, what you expect as the output, and what the actual output is. Then people can help you finding out why there is a difference between expected and actual output. A great tool is [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) to help understand why a program may not behave as expected.

Comment: So i am expecting the correct code where list of interger is captured from input functions and then find sum of integers in the list.

Comment: input =[1,2,3,4,5]  output =15

Comment: @user14887535 please [edit] the question to include that information. Also, please explain in the question WHY your current code doesn't do what you want, by showing what it does, and what you want it to do when it's working correctly.

Comment: Expectation is quite clear to store integer in list and then find the sum of integer stored in the List.

Comment: @user14887535 Of course the expectation from your point of view is clear. However, you have not shown any actual effort of debugging your own piece of code in the question at hand. We have no idea what part of the code you want us to help you "fix" while just reading the question. The comments are not the place for adding additional information that is needed to answer your problem. That should be inside of the body of the question. Now, once again, please [edit] your question to include all needed information for us to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst=map(int,input("Enter the elements with space between them: ").split())
print(sum(lst))
```

Comment: A =[]
sum_element=0
totalElements_in_List = 5 # assuming it is for example 100 elements
for iteration in range(5):
    A.append(int(input("Value #" + str(iteration) + " :")))
    
print(A)
for element in A:
    sum_element=sum_element+element

print(sum_element)

Comment: Can you pls run the above code? i guess not working.

Comment: It is working but instead of using for loop to get the sum you can use inbuilt function sum to get the sum of the list .

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to create a list with 8 elements. By writing `list(8)` you do not create a list with 8 elements, instead you create the list that has the number `8` as it's only element. So you just get `[8]`.

`list()` is not a Constructor (like what you might expect from other languages) but rather a 'Converter'. And `list('382')` will convert this `string` to the following `list`: `['3','8','2']`.

So to get the input list you might want to do something like this:

```py
my_list = []
for i in range(int(input('Length: '))):
    my_list.append(int(input(f'Element {i}: ')))
```

and then continue with your code for summation.

A more pythonic way would be

```py
my_list = [int(input(f'Element {i}: '))
           for i in range(int(input('Length: ')))]
```

For adding all the elements up you could use the inbuilt `sum()` function:

```py
my_list_sum = sum(my_list)
```